# Should I use SQLite to add this feature?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I need your advise on this, I'm currently developing a kinda family application.(Everything relates to the family)

I would like to add something similar to a family tree or the family members. (Using Table view) and each member/element on the list will have its own "view" containing a 50 words biography about him and his photo.

Since, I'm still new to iOS development and I still haven't worked with SQLite yet. Do you guys think SQLite is the best for this job? How about the photos. Is there a way to put a thumbnail photo for each member?

Comment: Raw SQLite is a waste of time.  Use Core Data, unless you need portability, then use something like FMDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does this well, though [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is generally considered the preferred iOS technology. There are a few situations where I might advise using SQLite over Core Data, but you haven't outlined any app requirements that would make me lean that direction.

If you do your own SQLite, though, I'd suggest you use something like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), so you spare yourself the hassles of writing SQLite code.

And, as I mentioned in the comment of another answer to this question, regarding images in Core Data or SQLite, you face a significant performance hit for that. If you're dealing with small images (e.g. thumbnails), it's fine, but if you're dealing with a lot of large images, you really might want to consider storing them in some directory structure under the Documents folder (and then store relative path names in your database). It not architecturally elegant to take the images out of the database and use the Documents folder, but for performance reasons you might want to do precisely that.

Answer (score 2):

No.  I would use [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) for this.  CoreData gives you the graphical modelling tools to build an object model and handles all the tedious housekeeping required to persist your object graph to disk.

The photos you would store as conventional files on disk and be modelled by a CoreData object that maintains a reference (URI or file path) to the photo.

Comment: I will give it a try today. Honestly, I have never worked with either of them yet. CoreData uses story mainboard and graphical modelling as you said. It would be wise for me to give this a first shot before SQLite. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I would use CoreData for this, it boils down to an SQLite database, but Apple have added their own wrapper round the SQLite database, making it really simple to use.

There are a number sample apps on the Developer Site as well as numerous Tuts available just by searching the phrase ["CoreData example"](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) in google, the link here is ro Raywenderlich which is a good place to start. I think once you go through this blog you'll be using CoreData more and more when you need to store things like this.

With regards to the thumbnail storage I would store those on the device and save the path to the file in the Database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use SQLite for this; in fact it's ideal for holding a family tree given its relational nature.

The photo data can be serialised into a byte stream (`NSData *`) and stored in a column as a blob.

Answer (score 1):

A database has the huge pro, that you can keep everything stored at one place.

You could (not that I recommend) also use a folder-structure to specify the data like /images/, /words/, /people/ and use the same name for everyone throughout the folders (tim.jpg, tim.txt, tim.dat )

Or use a small database to store everything in different tables all with relation to your "family(_members)" table.

You can also store images in a database, mostly as a blob (or base64 encoded or or or... yuck)

I don't know how well iOS stuff handles those database types of SQLite but you should be better of using a database for that.

Comment: Regarding images in Core Data or SQLite, you face a significant performance hit for that. If you're dealing with small images (e.g. thumbnails), it's fine, but if you're dealing with a lot of large images (e.g. you might have a photo gallery section), you really want to consider storing them in some directory structure under the Documents folder (and then store relative path names in your database). It not architecturally elegant to take the images out of the database and use the Documents folder, but for performance reasons you might want to do precisely that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options here.

If you are storing all of the info within the application itself (ie. the details aren't being fetched from the web somewhere), SQLite (as a CoreData backend) would probably be a good idea. Read up on using CoreData so that you don't end up reinventing the wheel, and so that your implementation provides a smooth scrolling experience that iPhone users expect.

The photos, however, need a different means of storage/retrieval.

A common technique is to implement a 2-level cache system. What this would entail is storing the pictures in individual files, but keeping some of them in-memory after they are retrieved for speed. You could then have a class that looks something like the following:

```
@interface ThumbnailManager : NSObject
{
    id<ImageCache> _imageCache; // You make this.
}

- (UIImage *)imageForFamilyMemberWithName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

That's similar to something I would do in your position.

Good luck!